# Implementation of logistic regression formula in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to build my own logistic regression function using stochastic gradient descent in R, but what I have right now makes the weights grow without bound and therefore never halts:

```
# Logistic regression
# Takes training example vector, output vector, learn rate scalar, and convergence delta limit scalar
my_logr <- function(training_examples,training_outputs,learn_rate,conv_lim) {
  # Initialize gradient vector
  gradient <- as.vector(rep(0,NCOL(training_examples)))
  # Difference between weights
  del_weights <- as.matrix(1)
  # Weights
  weights <- as.matrix(runif(NCOL(training_examples)))
  weights_old <- as.matrix(rep(0,NCOL(training_examples)))

  # Compute gradient
  while(norm(del_weights) > conv_lim) {

    for (k in 1:NROW(training_examples)) {
      gradient <- gradient + 1/NROW(training_examples)*
        ((t(training_outputs[k]*training_examples[k,]
            /(1+exp(training_outputs[k]*t(weights)%*%as.numeric(training_examples[k,]))))))
    }

    # Update weights
    weights <- weights_old - learn_rate*gradient
    del_weights <- as.matrix(weights_old - weights)
    weights_old <- weights

    print(weights)
  }
    return(weights)
}
```

The function can be tested with the following code:

```
data(iris) # Iris data already present in R    
# Dataset for part a (first 50 vs. last 100)
iris_a <- iris
iris_a$Species <- as.integer(iris_a$Species)
# Convert list to binary class
for (i in 1:NROW(iris_a$Species)) {if (iris_a$Species[i] != "1") {iris_a$Species[i] <- -1}}    
random_sample <- sample(1:NROW(iris),50)

weights_a <- my_logr(iris_a[random_sample,1:4],iris_a$Species[random_sample],1,.1)
```

I double-checked my algorithm against [Abu-Mostafa's](http://work.caltech.edu/library/091.html), which is as follows:

1. Initialize weight vector
2. For each time step compute gradient:
   `gradient <- -1/N * sum_{1 to N} (training_answer_n * training_Vector_n / (1 + exp(training_answer_n * dot(weight,training_vector_n))))`
3. `weight_new <- weight - learn_rate*gradient`
4. Repeat until weight delta is sufficiently small

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Am I missing a normalization term for the weights? Is this a Cross Validated problem, maybe?

Comment: From a mathematical perspective, an unconstrained magnitude on the weight vector does not yield a unique solution. When I added these two lines to the classifier function, it converged in two steps:

`weights <- weights/norm(weights)`

...

`weights <- weights_old - learn_rate*gradient`
`weights <- weights / norm(weights)`

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a mathematical perspective, an unconstrained magnitude on the weight vector does not yield a unique solution. When I added these two lines to the classifier function, it converged in two steps:

```
# Normalize
weights <- weights/norm(weights)
```

...

```
# Update weights
weights <- weights_old - learn_rate*gradient
weights <- weights / norm(weights)
```

I couldn't make @SimonO101's work, and I'm not using this code for real work (there are builtins like `glm`), so it's enough to do loops that I understand.
The whole function is as follows:

```
# Logistic regression
# Takes training example vector, output vector, learn rate scalar, and convergence delta limit scalar
my_logr <- function(training_examples,training_outputs,learn_rate,conv_lim) {
  # Initialize gradient vector
  gradient <- as.vector(rep(0,NCOL(training_examples)))
  # Difference between weights
  del_weights <- as.matrix(1)
  # Weights
  weights <- as.matrix(runif(NCOL(training_examples)))
  weights_old <- as.matrix(rep(0,NCOL(training_examples)))

  # Normalize
  weights <- weights/norm(weights)

  # Compute gradient
  while(norm(del_weights) > conv_lim) {

    for (k in 1:NCOL(training_examples)) {
      gradient <- gradient - 1/NROW(training_examples)*
        ((t(training_outputs[k]*training_examples[k,]
            /(1+exp(training_outputs[k]*t(weights)%*%as.numeric(training_examples[k,]))))))
    }
#     gradient <- -1/NROW(training_examples) * sum(training_outputs * training_examples / (1 + exp(training_outputs * weights%*%training_outputs) ) )

    # Update weights
    weights <- weights_old - learn_rate*gradient
    weights <- weights / norm(weights)
    del_weights <- as.matrix(weights_old - weights)
    weights_old <- weights

    print(weights)
  }
    return(weights)
}
```

Comment: +1. Looks good. I didn't fully understand the algorithm process. I'm setting about that this evening.

Comment: What do you mean "weights"? And how you calculate standard error and p values? Could you give some references of this algorithm also? Thanks!

Comment: I am also trying to implement logistic regression in c++, but using the IRLS algorithm, there is matrix inversion involved, quite a headache sometimes.

Comment: @qed Sorry for neglecting this! I don't recall what reference I used at the time, but Abu-Mostafa's lectures were and are my favorite general ML resource: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD63A284B7615313A

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems. Firstly, you can make much better use of R's vectorisation methods. Secondly, I am not an expert in stochastic gradient descent, but the algorithm you give below your question does not correspond to how you calculate your gradients in the function. Check this code carefully, but it seems to converge, and *I think* it follows  Abu-Mostfafa's. I gather that you want  to calculate the gradient this;

```
gradient <- -1/N * sum(training_outputs * training_examples / (1 + exp(training_outputs * dot( weights ,training_outputs) ) ) )
```

So this part of your algorithm should read...

```
while(norm(del_weights) > conv_lim) {  
gradient <- -1 / NROW(iris_a) * sum( training_outputs * training_examples / ( 1 + exp( training_outputs * as.matrix(training_examples) %*% weights ) ) )

# Update weights
weights <- weights_old - learn_rate*gradient
del_weights <- as.matrix(weights_old - weights)
weights_old <- weights
print(weights)
```

}

You can create a binary classification from the Species variable more easily using:

```
iris_a$Species <- as.numeric( iris_a$Species )
iris_a$Species[ iris_a$Species != 1 ] <- -1
```

I cannot tell you if the results returned are sensible, but that code should follow step 2. Check each step carefully, and remember R is vectorised so you can do element wise operations on vectors without loops. e.g.:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 1:5
x*y
#[1]  1  4  9 16 25
```

Comment: Well, that helped a lot (I was also masking the other binary iris sets incorrectly, which isn't shown here), but now I'm getting another weird result, which is that each classifier is training the same way: (http://i.imgur.com/qvamVQW.png)

Comment: It looks like all the weights are identical now when returned by the regression function. Are you sure those multiplications are right?

Comment: @TrevorAlexander Hi, no those multiplications aren't right, well spotted. I see you posted a working solution but I'd like to go back and sort out the vectorised code and make it work, because it's good practice!

Comment: I agree. I feel like being initially trained in C really crippled me when it came to programming for linear algebra.